# Queries related to browser cache

Tags: javascript, html, apache, http, caching

I am using browser cache to store my response data, but wanted to know how feasible it is to store the data in browser cache. Can anyone explain the following:

```
1. Is their a guarantee that the data will be cached for specific time, if I am storing only JSON data(can be huge).

2. What is the maximum size limit of browser cache.

3. Is my data cross domain accessible?If yes is their a way I can protect it?

4.Does the result vary from browser to browser?
```

Comment: are you refering to `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main storage method in modern browsers, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, in your case I assume you are using `localStorage`.

For `localStorage`:

- the data stored will be persistent as long as the user not clearing the data or you remove them using `localStorage.removeItem()`
- the maximum size of `localStorage` varies from browsers, basically there is at least 2.5MB. details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)
- `localStorage` works just like cookies, so you don't want to store any sensitive stuff, `SSL` between clicent and server is recommended
- IE 8 and above, Chrome 4, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10.5 and Safari 4 have already implemented this API

Details about `localStorage` in this [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: @Jacksonville I am setting the header as response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + 20); from my java server so is it going to use local storage in this case?

Comment: No, you're talking about setting cache in server side, I'm talking doing so in client side. I'm not familiar with server side settings, but the answer above is a alternative for you I guess.